# Unable to Copy SAP Fiori Tile Group between different clients of same system

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I am implementing SAP Fiori App's in Embedded Architecture(Gateway and Backend on the same system).

In development Client i.e 100,I have created Customizing Request in which Z-Catalog / Z-Group are saved.

Now to get the same in Testing Client 200,I have used `SCC1` to copy the Customizing Request created in Development Client to Testing Client.
But while creating `PFCG` role,I can see only Z-Catalog copied but not Z-Group.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that there is an issue with cache synchronization. 
You may try to invalidate the caches using:

Transaction: SPRO

[image]

Please note that it is not necessary to invalidate caches in normal operation.
If you can reproduce the issue, it might be there is a bug or a note is missing in the system.